# Need help making a program that enters data in a website utilizing the information stored in a variable

Tags: python, web, http-post

I am currently making a program that converts pdf to html and now i need to enter the scraped data that i removed from the html file into a website
This is the website : http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA

This is what I got so far :

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
import requests
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
        for file_name in file_name_list:
            if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
                continue
            with open(file_name) as markup:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
                text = soup.get_text()
                match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)", text)#To remove the names that appear, just remove the last (\S*), to add them is just add the (\S*), before it there was a \s*
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
                value = match
                url = 'http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA'
                query = {'field': value}
                res = requests.post(url, data=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your project idea, i might try it myself! Anyway, i suggest you use selenium. I visited your website and i made up the code to enter data into the first text box (Case Type) and the second one (Case Number) and then press enter. However you must install selenium first, which should be very easy.
To install selenium for windows:

- get the exact path where PIP is installed on your laptop.
- open CMD and paste in the path. Then add the following: " install selenium". Make sure that you leave a space after the path before typing this in
- selenium should install successfully. Now you have to install the webdriver. Visit: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
- Scroll down to the drivers section and install the appropriate driver for your browser.
- Place the downloaded file in the same location as your code.

And thats it. Now you can copy and paste the following wherever you need it in your code:

```
import time, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Chrome=  webdriver.Chrome()
Chrome.get("http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA")

casetype = Chrome.find_element_by_name("ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseNo")
casenumber = Chrome.find_element_by_name("ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseYear")
submit = Chrome.find_element_by_name("ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$btnSubmit")

casetype.send_keys("Hi")
casenumber.send_keys("Hey")
submit.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)
```

This will, as already said, fill in the first 2 text boxes and press the first submit. The code does this by finding the specific textbox you need using :

```
txtbx1 = Chrome.find_element_by_name("ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseNo")
```

Then it sends whatever data you need to send to it using :

```
txtbx1.send_keys("Hi")
```

and so on. You can use this info to modify the code and do exactly what you want. For example if you want to fill in the third text box on that page, then add the above 2 lines, replacing what is in the brackets by the name of the text box.

PS: To find out the name of the text box, go to your website, right click on the textbox, click inspect, then locate the part where it sais 'name' and copy the stuff in the qoutes after it. Thats it. if there is something you dont understand or something you want to know please comment below. And finally since you are using beautiful soup and requests, this might not fit you, but i assure you it still works!